# Is it possible to get candle high and low by using a set bar_index?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I have an set candle with for example (bar_index = 6900)

my question is, is it possible to get the candle information (low and high) for exactly this candle with this bar_index?

Comment: Nope. As far as I know, could be wrong though.

Comment: do you think there is any workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you can just keep track of your target bar by simply substracting your target from the `bar_index`.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)
target_bar_index = 10
n = bar_index < target_bar_index ? na : bar_index - target_bar_index
plot(bar_index < target_bar_index ? na : high[n], color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles)
plot(bar_index < target_bar_index ? na : low[n], color=color.red, style=plot.style_circles)
```

[image]